# Tomcat. Works in Eclipse, but does not work when deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have a project on tomcat that works well when I run it "on server" via Eclipse. However, when I exported the WAR file and deployed it, the servlets don't work. Only my JSP pages work.
Here's part of the web XML:

```
<display-name>CandC3</display-name>
```

Then, the `<welcome-file-list>` section and then servlets and mappings. Here's one:

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>candc3.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, when I try to access this servlet as someserver:8080/CandC3/LoginServlet?param1=val1
I get an error 404: Servlet LoginServlet is not available

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious? Shouldn't an export from eclipse work seamlessly in a server ;)

More info:
catalina.out

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive CandC3.war
Apr 24, 2013 11:10:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Also, after I restart tomcat, the first time I try to use the Servlet I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class candc3.LoginServlet or a class it depends on
```

and as the root cause:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: candc3.LoginServlet
```

After that, on subsequent tries I get `error 404: Servlet LoginServlet is not available`

Comment: Is the webapp running? Many things can cause this, you should take a look at the log files and post the exception. Also check the base url, is it the same as the .war file name?

Comment: [Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path)

Comment: You can consider posting the server boot up logs here with application already in webapps. They should show some information.

Comment: What would the boot up logs say? Is that Catalina.out? It does not seem to be very informative on this WAR. Where else can I get info?

Comment: I'd suspect that Tomcat unpacks the war and places it in a non-root context.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a web application under your tomcat/webapps directory named CandC3? Does it have a directory under it named WEB-INF with a "classes" directory or similar under it? Otherwise, can you physically locate your servlet class candc3.LoginServlet at all anywhere under the CandC3 directory?

Comment: Yes, the classes directory contains both java and class files. After a careful look at the logs, though, I found a different problem. The version of java in the server does not match the java version I used to compile the servlet, so the java files were not loaded.